# Fresh Windows 8.1, wireless ethernet adapter drivers missing, can't go online to install drivers

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, windows-8.1

Like title says, a fresh Windows 8.1 need drivers to function.
Not an issue if you happen to have a router, I do not. I have a phone, which I'm I intended to use to gain access to the internet via the computer. Issue is, the wireless drivers need to be installed first. Can't install drivers if I can not use drivers.

I visited the manefacturer's web-site, of Fujitsu - LifeBook - E Series - E549, and acquired the drivers on a different computer for wireless adapters. They were for Windows 10, though, and offered no Windows 8.1. It did not work, mostly since the computer is missing too many Windows KB files.

I don't suppose there's a magical fix for this?

Comment: You can search for the appropriate driver on the [windows update catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx) if you have ta device id.  Without Since you have not really provided any information required to answer your question, you should edit your question, to provide the appropriate level of detail.  The device in question, should be listed in device manager, even if a driver is not installed.  Windows 10 drivers cannot be used on earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: Make and specific model of PC?

Comment: Use mobile tethering and look for the drivers?

Comment: @DavidPostill doesn’t the mobile tethering using usb also need drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Since Window 8.1 is old, it may not have drivers for your PC, and manufacturers would not bother creating them.

Workaround: Try a *newer* operating system, such as Windows 10, or Linux. In fact, you can use a live Linux USB, such [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview), without having to install it on the HDD. That would allow you to use your PC to browse the web and to download Windows 8.1 drivers if you can find them. If not, install the newer OS.